# 'ListViewItemComparer' could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to sort my ListView alphabetically using Microsoft's example, however, the 'ListViewItemComparer' can't be found. I'm getting this error:

> CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ListViewItemComparer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried importing everything with the `using System;` directive, but I'm still getting an error.

Edit (With code):

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

....

```
// Determine whether the column is the same as the last column clicked.
        if (e.Column != sortColumn)
        {
            // Set the sort column to the new column.
            sortColumn = e.Column;
            // Set the sort order to ascending by default.
            officerListView.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
        }
        else
        {
            // Determine what the last sort order was and change it.
            if (officerListView.Sorting == SortOrder.Ascending)
                officerListView.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending;
            else
                officerListView.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
        }

        // Call the sort method to manually sort.
        officerListView.Sort();
        // Set the ListViewItemSorter property to a new ListViewItemComparer
        // object.
        this.officerListView.ListViewItemSorter = new ListViewItemComparer(e.Column,
                                                          officerListView.Sorting);
```

[Microsoft's Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/csharp/language-compilers/sort-listview-by-column)

Comment: A link to the example would help...

Comment: I added the code in the edit.

Comment: I just followed the link you provided and the text "ListViewItemComparer" does not appear anywhere on that page. You have not followed that example as it is. You haven't followed it all, in fact, because if you had then you would have actually defined that class yourself. The `ListView` expects an `IComparer` object in that context and it's up to you to provide the implementation that you want in your application, which that example demonstrates explicitly.

Comment: Specifically, you have ignored steps 7 and 8 in that tutorial.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I see. Thank you. I'm still new to programming so I wasn't quite sure what they were talking about. I just started programming last month, so I still have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no class with name `ListViewItemComparer` in the framework. Add it to your project and implement the `Compare`() method:

```
class ListViewItemComparer : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        // Implement the comparison logic here.
    }
}
```